# Multiple condition in one case statement using oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following sql and result:

```
SELECT oh.order_id,disallow_short_ship,sm.number
FROM table1 oh
    LEFT JOIN table2 sm
        ON sm.client_id = oh.client_id
            AND sm.site_id = oh.from_site_id
            AND sm.order_id = oh.order_id
WHERE oh.order_id = 'abc'
GROUP BY oh.order_id,oh.disallow_short_ship,sm.number
ORDER BY oh.order_id desc;
```

**Result:**

```
order_id   disallow_short_ship      number 
abc        null                     2107
abc        null                     2108
```

The expected result is to put case condition
if the order have more that one result then
compare both the number column,
the greater number(`2108`) should have `disallow_short_ship = 'Y'`
and for small number (`2107`) `disallow_short_ship = 'N'` as result.

I have tried to write case statement for `disallow_short_ship` column, but do I need to put two condition
within one case statement.

**Expected Result:**

```
order_id   disallow_short_ship   number 
abc        N                     2107
abc        Y                     2108
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use window functions and a `case` expression:

```
SELECT oh.order_id, disallow_short_ship, sm.number,
       (CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY oh.order_id) > 1 AND
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.order_id ORDER BY number) = 1
             THEN 'N'
             WHEN COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY oh.order_id) > 1 AND
                  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY oh.order_id ORDER BY number DESC) = 1
             THEN 'Y'
             ELSE disallow_short_ship
        END) as disallow_short_ship             
FROM table1 oh LEFT JOIN
     table2 sm
     ON sm.client_id = oh.client_id AND
        sm.site_id = oh.from_site_id AND
        sm.order_id = oh.order_id
WHERE oh.order_id = 'abc'
GROUP BY oh.order_id, oh.disallow_short_ship, sm.number
ORDER BY oh.order_id desc;
```

Comment: 2112: -30483-ORA-30483: window  functions are not allowed here getting error here

Comment: I am getting the above error while running the queryORA-30483: window functions are not allowed here getting error here

Comment: @user2907032 . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle?

Comment: it is large xml file extract query within which I am adding this case condition, when run this normal query i was not getting any error. but when I added as part of my large sql its started giving error as ORA-30483:

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: @user2907032 . . . Here is a db<>fiddle that illustrates that the syntax works:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3e97042e431218746c6f25765c400c3a.  Note:  `number` has to be put in quotes because it is an Oracle reserved word.

Comment: I have put in quotes   but in oracle i am still getting the same error ORA-30483: